# 'YoutubeService' does not exist in the namespace 'Google.Apis.Youtube.v3'

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

I am new to YouTube Api v3. I am trying to use code samples from documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

I tried "upload a video" sample and added related references to my project but I got this error.

When I look object browser I can see the YoutubeService class is there but compiler says that I'm wrong. here is picture of it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbw0l.png

what can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's YouTubeService, not Youtubeservice.

Comment: I can't believe this. How can this be in original samples. I spend 2 hours for that. Thanks for the answer, I will marked question solved in 8 minutes.

Comment: Nobody's perfect :) Not even Google developers.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a capitalization change in the PHP library recently. Please use YouTubeService going forward.